# How to get output from python2 subprocess which run a script using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, multiprocessing

Here is my demo code. It contains two scripts.

The first is `main.py`, it will call `print_line.py` with subprocess module.

The second is `print_line.py`, it prints something to the stdout.

main.py

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('python2 print_line.py',
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                     close_fds=True,
                     shell=True,
                     universal_newlines=True)

while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    if line:
        print(line)
    else:
        break
```

print_line.py

```
from multiprocessing import Process, JoinableQueue, current_process


if __name__ == '__main__':
    task_q = JoinableQueue()

    def do_task():
        while True:
            task = task_q.get()
            pid = current_process().pid
            print 'pid: {}, task: {}'.format(pid, task)
            task_q.task_done()

    for _ in range(10):
        p = Process(target=do_task)
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()

    for i in range(100):
        task_q.put(i)

    task_q.join()
```

Before, `print_line.py` is written with threading and Queue module, everything is fine. But now, after changing to multiprocessing module, the `main.py` cannot get any output from print_line. I tried to use `Popen.communicate()` to get the output or set `preexec_fn=os.setsid` in`Popen()`. Neither of them work.

So, here is my question:

1. Why subprocess cannot get the output with multiprocessing? why it is ok with threading?
2. If I comment out `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`, the output is printed in my console. Why? How does this happen?
3. Is there any chance to get the output from `print_line.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curious.

In theory this *should* work as it is, but it does not. The reason being somewhere in the deep, murky waters of buffered IO. It seems that the output of a subprocess of a subprocess can get lost if not flushed.

You have two workarounds:

One is to use `flush()` in your print_line.py:

```
def do_task():
    while True:
        task = task_q.get()
        pid = current_process().pid
        print 'pid: {}, task: {}'.format(pid, task)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        task_q.task_done()
```

This will fix the issue as you will flush your stdout as soon as you have written something to it.

Another option is to use `-u` flag to Python in your main.py:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('python2 -u print_line.py',
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                     close_fds=True,
                     shell=True,
                     universal_newlines=True)
```

`-u` will force stdin and stdout to be completely unbuffered in `print_line.py`, and children of `print_line.py` will then inherit this behaviour.

These are workarounds to the problem. If you are interested in the theory why this happens, it definitely has something to do with unflushed stdout being lost if subprocess terminates, but I am not the expert in this.

Comment: Thank you, your solution works. I never thought that buffer would cause this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a [multiprocessing](/questions/tagged/multiprocessing) issue, but it *is* a [subprocess](/questions/tagged/subprocess) issue—or more precisely, it has to to with standard I/O and buffering, as in [Hannu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47629593/1256452).  The trick is that by default, the output of *any* process, whether in Python or not, is *line buffered* if the output device is a "terminal device" as determined by `os.isatty(stream.fileno())`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.fileno()
1
>>> import os
>>> os.isatty(1)
True
```

There is a [shortcut available to you once the stream is open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects):

```
>>> sys.stdout.isatty()
True
```

but the `os.isatty()` operation is the more fundamental one.  That is, internally, Python inspects the file descriptor first using `os.isatty(fd)`, then chooses the stream's buffering based on the result (and/or arguments and/or the function used to open the stream).  The `sys.stdout` stream is opened early on during Python's startup, before you generally have much control.<sup>1</sup>

When you call [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) or [`codecs.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) or otherwise do your own operation to open a file, you can *specify* the buffering via one of the optional arguments.  The default for `open` is the system default, which is line buffering if `isatty()`, otherwise *fully buffered*.  Curiously, the default for `codecs.open` is *line buffered*.

A line buffered stream gets an automatic `flush()` applied when you write a newline to it.

An unbuffered stream writes each byte to its output immediately.  This is very inefficient in general.  A fully buffered stream writes its output when the buffer gets sufficiently full—the definition of "sufficient" here tends to be pretty variable, anything from 1024 (1k) to 1048576 (1 MB)—or when explicitly directed.

When you run something as a process, it's *the process itself* that decides how to do any buffering.  Your own Python code, reading *from* the process, cannot control it.  But if you know something—or a lot—*about* the processes that you will run, you can set up their environment so that they run line-buffered, or even unbuffered.  (Or, as in your case, since you *write* that code, you can write it to do what you want.)

---

<sup>1</sup>There are hooks that fire up very early, where you can fuss with this sort of thing.  They are tricky to work though.